# Chrome Extensions creating a .html page accessible by clicking browser action

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to look around the web and have had difficulties finding an answer. I've seen a couple of web extensions such as OneTab that open a local `index.html` page when you click the "browser action" button. Does anyone know how I can get my chrome extension to open an index.html page when "browser action" is pressed?

Comment: There's two different steps: doing something for the browser action's onclick, and having that something be "open a local html page".  Neither is particularly hard to look up how to do; which is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should take a look at [chrome.browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) and [chrome.runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL).

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Your Extension Name",
    "description": "Your Extension Description",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
         "title": "Your Browser Action Name"
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html") });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to open your local HTML page by a browser action.

### 1. As a popup

**manifest.json**

```
"browser_action":   {
                            "default_icon"  :   "128.png",
                            "default_popup" :   "localPage.html",
                            "default_title" :   "localPage title"
                        }
```

### 2. As a normal page in Google Chrome browser

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("localpage.html") });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are two parts for your question

### 1. Respond to `browserAction` clicked event

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
        // Your code here
    });
```

### 2. Open a local html page

You can get the local page url via `chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html")`

Then you can use `chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html") });` to open the local html page.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are outdated and no longer correct for Manifest Version 3.

In manifest.json, you need to use `action` and `service_worker`:

```json
{
    ...
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {},
    "background": {"service_worker": "background.js"}
}
```

(Note that you need `"action"` even if it's empty.)

In background.js, you need to use `chrome.action`:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html")
    });
});
```